# Deserialize nested classes of a request in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, gson

I have a problem with the deserialization of a request, which should translate into a java class with properties inside which are themselves other classes. The first level of deserialization works, but as regards the contained fields, for obvious reasons, I do not obtain the respective subclasses.

This is my code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class CustomForm extends GenericJson {

    private String formId;

    private CustomInfo info;


    private List<CustomItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
    private String linkedSheetId;
    
    
    private String responderUri;
    
    
    private String revisionId;
    
    
    private FormSettings settings;

    public CustomForm(Form form){
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(form, this);
        if(form.getInfo() != null){
            this.info = new CustomInfo(form.getInfo());
        }
        if(form.getItems() != null){
            for(Item item:form.getItems()){
                this.items.add(new CustomItem(item));
            }
        }
    }

    public Form getForm(){
        Form form = new Form();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, form);
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for(CustomItem item:this.items){
            items.add(item.getItem());
        }
        form.setItems(items);
        if(!this.info.isEmpty()) {
            form.setInfo(this.info.getInfo());
        }
        return form;
    }
}
```

and this is my request:

```
{
    "formId": "1234",
    "info": {
        "documentTitle": "Untitled form",
        "title": "prova"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "itemId": "123",
            "questionItem": {
                "question": {
                    "choiceQuestion": {
                        "options": [
                            {
                                "value": "Newsletter"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "Magazine"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "Social Network"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "Siti"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "Associazioni di categoria"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "Aziende partner"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "Comunicazione interna all\u0027azienda"
                            }
                        ],
                        "type": "DROP_DOWN"
                    },
                    "questionId": "123"
                }
            },
            "title": "Come sei venuto a conoscenza di questo Corso?"
        },
        {
            "itemId": "123",
            "questionGroupItem": {
                "grid": {
                    "columns": {
                        "options": [
                            {
                                "value": "PESSIMO"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "MEDIOCRE"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "SUFFICIENTE"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "BUONO"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "OTTIMO"
                            }
                        ],
                        "type": "RADIO"
                    }
                },
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "questionId": "123",
                        "rowQuestion": {
                            "title": "Pulizia delle aule"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "questionId": "123",
                        "rowQuestion": {
                            "title": "Materiale fornito"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "questionId": "123",
                        "rowQuestion": {
                            "title": "Competenza docente"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "questionId": "123",
                        "rowQuestion": {
                            "title": "Completezza contenuti"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "questionId": "123",
                        "rowQuestion": {
                            "title": "Applicabilità delle nozioni"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "questionId": "123",
                        "rowQuestion": {
                            "title": "Rispondenza ad aspettative"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "questionId": "123",
                        "rowQuestion": {
                            "title": "Gentilezza del personale"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "responderUri": "https://example.om",
    "revisionId": "00000005"
}
```

The question is: is there any annotation that allows me to associate the request fields with their respective nested classes?

Comment: No annotation needed, this generally works out of the box. When you say "but as regards the contained fields, for obvious reasons, I do not obtain the respective subclasses", what *exactly* happens? Error message? No value? Something else?

Comment: i get a LinkedHashMap instead my CustomClass, and then i get error 500 when i try to invoke his methods.

Comment: What are you talking about? I don't see a `CustomClass` in your example. And you *can't* get a `Map`, because that doesn't fit in the `CustomForm` class. Please add the code that does the deserialization and add details about what actually happens when you run it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain well. When I invoke the getter method of the `CustomInfo info` property, I get `null`, but in the request that property is set.

Comment: What serialization library are you using? You have tagged your question with both Jackson and Gson.  If you are using Jackson then take a look at @JsonTypeInfo e.g. here https://www.baeldung.com/java-jackson-polymorphic-deserialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

This constructor do the trick.

```
@JsonCreator
public CustomForm(
        @JsonProperty("formid") String formId,
        @JsonProperty("info") CustomInfo info,
        @JsonProperty("items") List<CustomItem> items,
        @JsonProperty("linkedSheetId") String linkedSheetId,
        @JsonProperty("responderUri") String responderUri,
        @JsonProperty("revisionId") String revisionId,
        @JsonProperty("settings") FormSettings settings
){
    this.formId = formId;
    this.info = info;
    this.items = items;
    this.linkedSheetId = linkedSheetId;
    this.responderUri = responderUri;
    this.revisionId = revisionId;
    this.settings = settings;
}
```